# Continues Integration with IOS

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am looking for the best way to get my `Xcode` Apps on `CI`.
I already have a designated Jenkins server which is Integrated with `BitBucket`.
I want to know what would be the best option.
Do I use Xcode server or is there a way I can also use my Jenkins server to build my Xcode apps through a slave server that is run on a Mac?
Thank you for your Help.